# Shaders draw unexpected transparent background

Tags: libgdx, glsl, shader

I have a new class `MyActor` extended Actor, with applying shader into it.

However, the shader will fill up the transparent background unexpectedly.

`draw()` method codes inside `MyActor` as follow:

```
@Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if(shaderProgram!=null)
        {
            batch.setShader(shaderProgram);           
        }

        if(!drawParentAtBack)super.draw(batch, parentAlpha); // by default is false
        Color c = getColor(); // used to apply tint color effect
        batch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, c.a * parentAlpha);
        if ( isVisible() )
        {            
                if(displayFrame !=null) // a textureregion
                {
                    batch.draw(displayFrame,
                            getX(),getY(),
                            getOriginX(),getOriginY(),
                            getWidth(),getHeight(),
                            getScaleX(),getScaleY(),
                            getRotation());
                }           
        }
        if(drawParentAtBack)super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        if(shaderProgram!=null)
        {
            batch.setShader(null);
        }
}


public void setShader(String vs, String fs){
        vertexShaderCode   =    Gdx.files.internal("shaders/" + vs + ".vs").readString();
        fragmentShaderCode = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/" + fs + ".fs").readString();
        shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(vertexShaderCode, fragmentShaderCode);
        if (!shaderProgram.isCompiled())
        {
            d( "Shader compile error: " + shaderProgram.getLog() );
        }
    }
```

My definition goes like this:

```
     MyActor myActor1;myActor2;
     ..... // setting up myActor1 & myActor2
     myActor1.setShader("default","greyScale");
     myActor2.setShader("default","greyScale");
```

my simple shaderCodes from [this tutorial](https://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/07/08/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-12-Using-GLSL-Shaders-and-creating-a-Mesh.aspx):

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {
        vec3 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).rgb;
        float gray = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
        vec3 grayscale = vec3(gray);

        gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale, 1.0);
}
```

My vertex shader codes from [this tutorial](https://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/07/08/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-12-Using-GLSL-Shaders-and-creating-a-Mesh.aspx):

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {
        vec3 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).rgb;
        float gray = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
        vec3 grayscale = vec3(gray);

        gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale, 1.0);
}
```

My expected result images are gray color shapes with transparent background, BUT it turns out like this:

[image: error image]

sample shape image without shader:

[image: sample shape assets without any shader]

Any helps please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general transparency is achieved [Alpha Blending](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Blending). The alpha channel of the fragment controls the transparency and has to be set.

In the fragment shader the alpha channel of the texture is omitted:

> ```c
> gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale, 1.0);
> ```

Set the alpha channel of the texture (`u_texture`) to the alpha channel of the output (`gl_FragColor.a`):

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {

        // read RGB color channels and alpha channel
        vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);

        float gray = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
        vec3 grayscale = vec3(gray);

        // write gray scale and alpha channel
        gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale.rgb, color.a);
}
```